# WebRTC: data transfer issue

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I'm trying to send ArrayBuffer using WebRTC and [`simple-peer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) package. And I got these issues:

- Another browser receives several events with Uint8Arrays which are part of the original ArrayBuffer. Length of each Uint8Array is not greater than 262528. It happens when I send large ArrayBuffer from chrome to chrome.
- I get `TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.` error on sender browser when I send large ArrayBuffer from firefox to chrome.

But everything is fine when:

- ArrayBuffer length is small.
- when I send data from chrome to firefox.

I use `peer.send(data)` and `peer.on('data', callback)` functions from `simple-peer` and code is really simple so I have no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: I'm having trouble following when it works and when it doesn't. Can you rephrase as a question? Are you [specifying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53328431/918910) `binaryType`?

Comment: I'm using `simple-peer` so it specifies `binaryType` for me. I've got the cause of the problem and made an answer below. The reason is message size limitations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [THAT](https://viblast.com/blog/2015/2/5/webrtc-data-channel-message-size/) article, there are a message size limitations.
The conclusion is:

> All In all, the takeaway is that a 16 Kbyte message size is the one
>   allowing for the highest throughput, while also being the most
>   portable one. By the way, in some WebRTC tutorials and literature, the
>   authors recommend using 16 Kbytes but they don’t tell you why. Well
>   now you know.